# Objective-C: What is the date format for a date like 2014-02-02T20:55:31.555Z

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to use `NSDateFormatter` to translate date strings I'm getting back in JSON. An example of such a date is `2014-02-02T20:55:31.555Z`. I cannot, however, figure out what the correct date format is. I thought this would be it: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'` - no luck.

Comment: You're missing the fractional seconds at the end, look up the symbol for those. On mobile, can't look it up right now.

Comment: you're totally right - the format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. if you want to answer, i'll accept

Comment: [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, for the record. @Undo's got it.

Comment: Read [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  Every iOS programmer should have it bookmarked in their browser.

Comment: I did look at that and was still unclear. I failed to register the .SSS portion of my date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the fractional seconds at the end of the date, you'll need to add them to your format string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

Comment: Should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`.